# Windows COM - how to debug a COM server

Tags: com

I have a com server(written in C++, ATL) that runs out of process. In one of my computers I am able to debug the server code easily just by starting the COM under the debugger, setting breakpoints and connection to the server from a client process.

On my another computer this does not happen, if I start the COM server under the debugger from start, the client uses another instance of the same server and the only way to debug the server is to attch to it after the client already started it. How can this be configured ?

Comment: It might have another version of the COM server installed in that machine? Try to search for COM server in system registry and if it happened, unistall the other one.

Comment: Have you tried getting the COM to invoke the debugger by generating an error. eg Assert(0) When it reaches the error it will ask you if you want to start debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the fact that under the Vista and up when you start the com server elevated (so that the registry part gets in registry at the end of the build) the COM client will launch another COM server instance (at the same integrity level as he was, e.g. medium and not high)

So I had to run Visual Studio for the server as normal user (not run as admin) and had to do the COM registration from command line.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wasn't actually trying to debug the initialization of my out-of-process server yet, but I didn't understand why another process instance kept popping up since ATL should have registered the class for multiuse.

Answer (score 2):

Start your processes normally. Make the debugger stop at a break point in your COM client. Launch another instance of Visual Studio (I am assuming you are running Visual Studio), and attach to the out of proc server process. In Visual Studio 2008, you do it by selecting *Attach to process...* in the *Tools* menu. Then simply select the process you want to debug, and there you go. You may want to open the source code files manually to set break points, because you are not debugging within the context of the original project.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. I would like to be able to start my server directly from de debugger, otherwise I will miss some "initialization" steps in my server by the time I will be able to attch to the already started server