# How to debug a COM C++ Out of Process Server ? (client: Excel vba)

Tags: excel, com, atl, vba

I don't know how to debug a COM ATL C++ out of process exe server with Visual Studio 2015.

For a COM ATL DLL there is no problem, the breakpoints are automatically triggered when I call the COM dll. However when I try to debug an EXE server, the debugger didn't break. Indeed the exe server is only loaded at demand and the debug symbols of the exe server are not loaded when the client starts.

My client, that call the COM server, is Excel VBA (I have added the reference to the com exe, in the VBA editor, via Tools/References). To debug it, I set the path to Excel.exe in the Visual Studio Debug command and as argument I set the path to my xlsm file. Then I just call call the VBA code in Excel. It works for the com DLL but not for the COM Exe. I also tried by attaching VS to Excel and it didn't work.

I have found this post ( [Windows COM - how to debug a COM server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045722/windows-com-how-to-debug-a-com-server) ), it seems this is caused by a elevation/permission issue,  but I tried the proposed answer but it didn't works.

Does any one can help me with this ?

**How do you debug an out-of-process com server ?**

Is it necessary to attach a debugger to the client that consumes the EXE server (so in my case to excel) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky trying to debug an EXE server.

What I would do is modify the registry so that you are prompted to debug the EXE when it is loaded.

Here is the contents of an exported .reg file used to modify the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\YourExeName.exe]
"debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
```

Change YourExeName.exe to something more useful...

When your EXE server is launched, you will be prompted to launch a debugger or attach from a current running instance of a debugger.  It is faster and better to already have a debugger running... When I say "debugger", a running instance of Visual Studio is fine.

A problem when trying to debug an EXE server is that when you set breakpoints and step through the code, you can exceed the COM timeout and then the EXE client calling your process will have a failed call due to timeout and it will just continue executing.  When everything is in process, this is not such a problem.  For an EXE, it might be helpful to have a lot more TRACE statements in your debug build in the area where you think you might have problems.

It is not strictly necessary to attach to the client process.  Sometimes it is helpful, and sometimes not.  It's obviously much more easier if you have the source code to the calling client process.

Comment: One trick I do when finished debugging this way is to go to the registry and prefix the registry key with an underscore, like this: _YourExeName.exe. 

It does two things... 1) stops the prompt for the debugger, 2) if i want to debug the EXE again, it's easier to find because it is the first listed in Image File Execution Options key and I can just delete the underscore to go back to debugging in this manner.

Comment: It works thanks a lot Joe, problem solved ! You have just saved my day :) there is almost nothing on the web about it and your answer is, by far, the best information I have read about it :) Also thanks for the trick. For others : follow this answer and it is just necessary to skip the first call to the debugger that correspond to the '/RegServer' call. Just build the COM server, skip the first call to the JIT debugger, run your client and the debugger will pop up when the server is called. Great, + be aware of the timeout problem